# C++ sprintf output order is incorrect

Tags: c++, printf

I have the following code that should output;

```
1234 : abcd
```

However I get

```
1234abcd :
```

```
        char string1[4];
        sprintf(string1,"1234");

        char string2[4];
        sprintf(string2,"abcd");

        sprintf(text_string,"%s : %s",string1,string2);
```

How can I get the sprintf to output in the correct order? I tried adding the " : " as a third string in the middle, but was still added to the end.

Comment: You forget that in C++ `char` strings are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. This *null-terminator* is what tells the end of the string, and it of course needs space for itself. That means a string of four characters really needs space for *five*. What you're doing now will write the null-terminator out of bounds of your arrays, which leads to *[undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Besides the obvious solution, to increase the size of the arrays, the natural C++ solution is of course to use `std::string` instead of character arrays and the old C function `sprintf`.

Comment: Thanks, increasing the substrings size's to 5 worked.

Answer (score 2):

You have undefined behavior: The `sprintf()` calls both write five characters (four characters payload + one terminating null byte) to an array that is only four characters long. After the first call to `sprintf()` all bets are off.

---

That said, what happens is, that the second `sprintf()` call overwrites the terminating null character that was written by the first `sprintf()` call, and thus the final `sprintf()` keeps printing through the second string until it finds that string's terminating null byte. I have no clue why the second string does not appear a second time in the output, but I don't have to: Since you have undefined behavior, anything is allowed to happen. Including the appearance of pink elephants...